# Export data to excel is not working

Tags: c#, excel, infragistics, ignite-ui

I am using Infragistics Excel Export framework for exporting data to excel through ajax post

Here is code at client side

```
  $.ajax({
        type: 'post',           
        url: '../Common/ExcelExporter',
        data: {
            tbname: parameter, pageNumber: _pageNumber, pageSize: _pageSize
            , exportType: true, exportFormat: true
        },
        success: function (res, status, xhr) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(xhr));
    }
    });
```

and the code at controller side

```
public void ExcelExporter(string tbname,int pageNumber, int pageSize, bool exportType, bool exportFormat)
{
    pageNumber++;
    IEnumerable exportdata = dbList.getClass(tbname);
    bool exportAllPages = exportType;

    if (exportdata == null) {
        var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(assemblyName + ".Models." + tbname));        

        if (exportAllPages)
        {
           exportdata = (from e in dbList.getClass(tbname).AsQueryable() select e).AsQueryable();
        }
        else
        {
            exportdata = (from e in dbList.getClass(tbname).AsQueryable() select e).AsQueryable().Skip(pageNumber).Take(pageSize);
        }

    WorkbookFormat excelFormat;

    if (exportFormat)
        excelFormat = WorkbookFormat.Excel2007;
    else
        excelFormat = WorkbookFormat.Excel97To2003;

    ExcelExportingModel exportModel = new ExcelExportingModel(excelFormat);
    exportModel.PopulateExcelWorkbook(exportdata);
    SendForDownload(exportModel.ExcelWorkbook, excelFormat);            
}

[SecuritySafeCritical]
private void SendForDownload(Workbook document, WorkbookFormat excelFormat)
{
    string documentFileNameRoot;          
    documentFileNameRoot = string.Format("Document.{0}", excelFormat == WorkbookFormat.Excel97To2003 ? "xls" : "xlsx");           
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + documentFileNameRoot);
    Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";           
    document.SetCurrentFormat(excelFormat);
    document.Save(Response.OutputStream);       
    Response.End();           
}
```

The code is executing without any error but there is no output.No file is being downloaded.
when i checked the response from the controller i am getting this

Output:

```
{
 "readyState":4,
 "responseText":"PK\u0002\u\<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>Relationships xmlns=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships\"><Relationship Type= \"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties\" Target=\"docProps/app.xml\" Id=\"rId1\" /><Relationship Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties\"Target=\"docProps/core.xml\" Id=\"rId2\" /><Relationship Type= \"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument\"Target=\"xl/workbook.xml\" Id=\"rId3\" />/Relationships>PK\u[Content_Types].xmlPK\u0005\u0000",
 "status":200,
 "statusText":"OK"
}
```

I have taken reference for code from this [**link**](http://www.igniteui.com/infragistics-excel/overview)

Please help to solve this

Comment: Did you try saving it to a memory stream and then writing it to Response.OutputStream.Write? Or response.writefile?

Comment: No,Can you tell me how to do in that way

Comment: Write the file to the disk in temporary folder and then use `Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType="application/octet-stream";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=Test.xlsx");
            Response.WriteFile("C:\\Temp\\Test.xlsx");`

Comment: its giving file not found exception

Comment: You need to write the file in a location which is accessible to the ASP.Net user. If the file is saved inside your application folder you can use Server.MapPath to locate the file.

Answer (score 1):

@Nilesh is on the right track, but you want to use an actual memory stream, not a temporary file.

Replace

```
document.Save(Response.OutputStream);
```

with

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    document.Save(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    ms.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
}
```

I have seen this with other Excel writer libraries. The reason is that not all streams are created equal; Some streams, like files and memory streams, allow you to move around in them, using things like the Position property. Other streams can only be read to or written from; In principle when you write to `Response.OutputStream` each character you write to the stream is sent to the user's browser so you can't "go back" (in practice the response stream may or may not be buffered but that is another discussion). The Excel library needs the ability to navigate inside the stream, hence why it is unable to save directly to the `OutputStream`.

Do bear in mind that using this approach you will have two copies of the spreadsheet in memory; one in the Excel library and a copy in the memory stream. This shouldn't be a problem unless you are creating lots of large spreadsheets in parallel, but you should be mindful of it.

Comment: Do you mean that with the memory stream it is no longer throwing an exception, but you get no output? If so, did you remember ms.Position=0? Try checking the length of the memory stream in debug to see if there is actually any content.

Comment: Ah, ExcelExporter is your action,  right? You may want to try: instead of directly writing to the response stream,  instead return a FileStreamResult. I've got some code I can share but I'm out at the moment.

Comment: the controller code was fine,i just changed the client code by using window.location=url instead of ajax post.Now its working